# How to convert from TSX to JSX in this Codesandbox

Tags: reactjs, node-sass

I am learning React and JavaScript and now I have this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cards-tsx-to-jsx-zzfoc) but I can't convert it to JavaScript React I have tried this for the `Card` Component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Card = props => {
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(false);

  const RenderCard = (className) => {
    return (
      <div
        className={`card ${className}${expanded ? " expanded" : ""}`}
        onClick={() => {
          setExpanded(!expanded);
        }}
      >
        <div className="image">
          <img alt="digger" src={props.image} />
        </div>
        <div className="info">
          <div
            className="bg1"
            style={{ backgroundImage: "url('" + props.image + "')" }}
          />
          <div
            className="bg2"
            style={{ backgroundImage: "url('" + props.image + "')" }}
          />
          <div
            className="bg3"
            style={{ backgroundImage: "url('" + props.image + "')" }}
          />

          <h1>JCB OES System</h1>
          <h2>Report Number #1</h2>
          <h3>Load lifter work area</h3>

          <div className="button">Open</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className={`card-container${expanded ? " expanded" : ""}`}>
      {expanded && <div className="background" />}
      {<RenderCard className="card1"/>}
      {<RenderCard className="card2"/>}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Card;
```

And I show the `Card` like this. It's very simple, it's just that when I click a card it does not pop up like the CodeSandbox does.

```
import Card from "./Card";
import "./styles.scss";

const CreateContent = () => {
 
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/jli8mqj.css" />

      <Card image="https://www.thetimes.co.uk/imageserver/image/methode%2Fsundaytimes%2Fprodmigration%2Fweb%2Fbin%2Fbeae8dfb-0a41-4f8e-b076-ffd68417287b.jpg?crop=1024%2C683%2C0%2C0&resize=685" />
      <Card image="https://www.virginexperiencedays.co.uk/content/img/product/large/PJCBRA__01.jpg" />
      <Card image="https://www.toyfarmers.co.uk/images/britains-jcb-3cx-backhoe-loader.jpg" />
      <Card image="https://seatylive.blob.core.windows.net/eventimages/2019-Aug-20-Tue_18-37-31-969.png" />
    </div>
  );
};

export default CreateContent;
```

The styles is the same, with no changes: I understand that the `expanded background` when set to `expanded=true` using the hook that the scss style for background should be in effect but all I get is a black screen.

```
.app {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4em 0;
  }
  
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
  }
  
  .card-container {
    font-family: niveau-grotesk, sans-serif !important;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    
    &.expanded {
      z-index: 3;
  
      @keyframes fade-in {
        0%   { opacity: 0; }
        100% { opacity: 1; }
      }
  
      .background {
        animation: fade-in .3s ease-out;
        z-index: 2;
        position: fixed;
        background: black;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }
    }
  
    .card {
      margin: 0 auto;
      width: 25em;
      cursor: pointer;
      border-radius: .5em;
      box-shadow: 0 50px 100px -20px rgba(50,50,93,.25), 
        0 30px 60px -30px rgba(0,0,0,.3), 
        0 -18px 60px -10px rgba(0,0,0,.03);
      margin-bottom: 4em;
  
      &.card2 {
        transition: .2s ease-out;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        width: 25em;
        left: 50%;
        z-index: 4;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
  
        &.expanded {
          width: 40em;
        }
      }
    
      .image {
        img {
          display: block;
          border-top-left-radius: .5em;
          border-top-right-radius: .5em;
          width: 100%;
        }
      }
  
      $button-color: rgb(87, 87, 228);
  
      &:hover {
        .info .button {
          color: white;
          background: $button-color;
        }
      }
  
      .info {
        background: white;
        position: relative;
        border-bottom-left-radius: .5em;
        border-bottom-right-radius: .5em;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding: .9em 1.2em;
        text-align: left;
  
        $darkness: 0;
  
        &:after {
          content: '';
          position: absolute;
          top: -20%;
          left: -20%;
          right: -20%;
          bottom: -20%;
          height: 140%;
          width: 140%;
          // filter: blur(8px);
          // -webkit-filter: blur(8px);
          background: linear-gradient(to right, 
            rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 30%, 
            rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
        }
  
        .bg1, .bg2 {
          position: absolute;
          top: -20%;
          left: -20%;
          right: -20%;
          bottom: -20%;
          height: 140%;
          width: 140%;
          z-index: 0;
          background-position: center;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          background-size: 100%;
          transform: rotate(180deg);
          filter: blur(16px);
        }
  
        .bg2 {
          background-position: bottom;
          transform: rotate(0deg);
          opacity:0.4;
        }
  
        .bg3 {
          background-position: top;
          transform: rotate(180deg);
          opacity:0.4;
        }
  
        .button {
          transition: .2s ease-out;
          text-transform: uppercase;
          line-height: 1.2em;
          position: absolute;
          top: 50%;
          transform: translateY(-50%);
          right: 1.8em;
          z-index: 1;
          background: white;
          border-radius: 1em;
          padding: .4em 1.1em;
          font-weight: 600;
          color: $button-color;
        }
  
        h1, h2, h3 {
          -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
          -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
          max-width: 13em;
          color: white;
          position: relative;
          z-index: 1;
          text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
        }
  
        h1 {
          line-height: .8em;
          letter-spacing: .03em;
          font-size: 1.1em;
          font-weight: 900;
          padding: .1em 0;
        }
  
        h2 {
          letter-spacing: .02em;
          font-size: 1.0em;
          font-weight: 400;
          padding: .1em 0;
          opacity: 0.6;
        }
  
        h3 {
          letter-spacing: .02em;
          font-size: .9em;
          font-weight: 400;
          padding: .1em 0;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Change both TSX files to JSX using the rename function in code sandbox. Go to your package.json and change "main" to "src/index.jsx" go to Card.jsx and remove all the typescript types. i.e. https://codesandbox.io/s/cards-tsx-to-jsx-forked-er3d6?file=/package.json

Comment: ok I wrote `{<RenderCard className="card1"/>}` instead of your `{renderCard("card1")}` confusing this syntax. please ad an answer I can approve
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To swap your Code Sandbox from TypeScript to JavaScript you should just need to:

1. Remove all typescript specific syntax from your ".ts" and ".tsx" files (interfaces, typings, etc)
2. Change all the file extensions to their JavaScript equivalent i.e. ".ts" -> ".js" and ".tsx" -> ".jsx".
3. Update the "main" property of the "package.json" file to point to the renamed entry point. i.e. "src/index.jsx".

I created a quick [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cards-tsx-to-jsx-forked-er3d6?file=/package.json) with this already done.

Comment: What if the .tsx has interfaces defined?

Comment: Interfaces are not part of JavaScript and should be removed as mentioned in step 1. This was a pretty short response more specific to the OPs exact case. If you are actually changing a project / solution from JavaScript to Typescript you will probably want to swap out the interfaces or types being used for component properties with PropTypes to give you some kind of type checking on your component properties.